# ESP8266 with Nodemcu and the http-modul: sequencing a POST operation after a GET failed. No callback-method

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

i want to make a button with my ESP8266. It needs to communicate with my local Synapse (Matrix.org) Server. 
I need to get my access_key, and a room_id and need to login my ESP8266.

So i have three http-methods. Each of it works fine, but when they are all three on my ESP8266 then it doesnt work. It seems that the first one dosent get a response but the second one. And then the skript stops because of some variable are nil. Thats why i didnt post the third-method.

```
My NodeMcu-Firmeware:
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
   branch: master
   commit: 22e1adc4b06c931797539b986c85e229e5942a5f
   SSL: true
   modules: bit,cjson,crypto,encoder,file,gpio,http,net,node,sntp,tmr,uart,wifi,tls
  build     built on: 2017-05-01 14:03
powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.0.0(656edbf)
```

My Code:

```
`ok, jsonheader = pcall(cjson.encode, {Accept="application/json"})
 if ok then
    print(jsonheader)
 else
    print("failed to encode!")
 end

 ok, jsonbody = pcall(cjson.encode, {type="m.login.password",user="admin", password="admin"})
 if ok then
    print(jsonbody)
 else
    print("failed to encode!")
 end


http.post("http://localhost:8008/_matrix/client/r0/login", jsonheader, jsonbody  , function(code, data)
if (code< 0) then
        print("HTTP_GET request failed")

    else

        print(code, data)
        accessToken = cjson.decode(data).access_token
        print(accessToken)
    end
end)






http.get("http://localhost:8008/_matrix/client/r0/directory/room/%23ButtonPrinter%3Ahomeserver", jsonheader, function(code1, data1)
if (code1< 0) then
        print("HTTP_GET request failed")
else
        print("___________________________________")
        print(code1, data1)
        roomId = cjson.decode(data1).room_id
        print(roomId)

    end
end)
```

The print out shows me, that it is not going in the first callback-method from http.post.

```
pin:6, level:1 
Calling: 00000001
LED On
Push Counter is: 3
___________________________________
 200    {"room_id":"!TpYsyBpFLoxXrbVBZv:homeserver","servers"["homeserver"]}
 !TpYsyBpFLoxXrbVBZv:homeserver
```

And the log-file from the server shows that:

```
2017-05-06 10:09:16,233 - synapse.storage.TIME - 215 - INFO - - Total database time: 0.000% {update_cached_last_access_time(0): 0.000%, store_device(0): 0.000%, get_users_in_room(0): 0.000%} {}
2017-05-06 10:09:18,246 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 59 - INFO - GET-6- 192.168.178.XX - 8008 - Received request: GET /_matrix/client/r0/directory/room/%23ButtonPrinter%3Ahomeserver
2017-05-06 10:09:18,249 - synapse.util.async - 201 - INFO - GET-6- Acquired linearizer lock 'state_resolve_lock' for key frozenset([17, 18])
2017-05-06 10:09:18,250 - synapse.util.async - 208 - INFO - GET-6- Releasing linearizer lock 'state_resolve_lock' for key frozenset([17, 18])
2017-05-06 10:09:18,251 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 91 - INFO - GET-6- 192.168.178.XX - 8008 - {None} Processed request: 4ms (0ms, 0ms) (0ms/2) 69B 200 "GET /_matrix/client/r0/directory/room/%23ButtonPrinter%3Ahomeserver HTTP/1.1" "None"
2017-05-06 10:09:18,253 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 59 - INFO - POST-7- 192.168.178.XX - 8008 - Received request: POST /_matrix/client/r0/login
2017-05-06 10:09:18,545 - synapse.handlers.auth - 433 - INFO - POST-7- Logging in user @admin:homeserver on device DWOVBGCIOD
2017-05-06 10:09:18,548 - synapse.access.http.8008 - 91 - INFO - POST-7- 192.168.178.XX - 8008 - {None} Processed request: 295ms (0ms, 0ms) (3ms/5) 364B 200 "POST /_matrix/client/r0/login HTTP/1.1" "None"
2017-05-06 10:09:21,198 - synapse.handlers.typing - 79 - INFO - - Checking for typing timeouts
2017-05-06 10:09:21,199 - synapse.handlers.presence - 329 - INFO - - Handling presence timeouts
2017-05-06 10:09:26,197 - synapse.handlers.typing - 79 - INFO - - Checking for typing timeouts
2017-05-06 10:09:26,198 - synapse.handlers.presence - 329 - INFO - - Handling presence timeouts
2017-05-06 10:09:26,232 - synapse.storage.TIME - 215 - INFO - - Total database time: 0.042% {store_device(2): 0.017%, add_device_change_to_streams(1): 0.010%, add_access_token_to_user(1): 0.009%} {}
```

I tried so much, i wrapped all in tail-method, a tried it with an alarm.
But nothing works. I need all response in the right sequence.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's sort of a classic.

> It is **not** possible to execute concurrent HTTP requests using this module.

Source: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/

Since all `http.xxx` operations are asynchronous (all NodeMCU functions with callbacks are...) you're effectively trying to run `http.post` and `http.get` in parallel.

**Solution 1: request chaining**

```
http.post(url, jsonheader, jsonbody, function(code, data)
  if (code < 0) then
    print("HTTP request failed")
  else
    print(code, data)
    -- http.get()
  end
end)
```

**Solution 2: task dispatching**

```
http.post(url, jsonheader, jsonbody, function(code, data)
  if (code < 0) then
    print("HTTP request failed")
  else
    print(code, data)
    node.task.post(function()
      -- http.get()
    end)
  end
end)
```

See https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/node/#nodetaskpost for details.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. that is what i throught. and i read the quote on the NodeMcu docs. but i throught its something when you have a http-method and in the callback function you put another http method, like you showed me in the solution. i will tried both of you solution and will write later if it fits for me. thanks

Comment: We added the chaining feature last December: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1629

Comment: ah okay, okay, thanks alot. the first solution works fine now. the code struckture is not so nice, but now i have a solution and with that, i can make the code more beautiful, maybe with the node-module. thanks alot it helped me alot. :)

Comment: "the code struckture is not so nice" - obviously each HTTP request could/should go into its own function. That'll leave you with a pretty concise structure. In each HTTP callback you'd then simply invoke another function (that encapsulates `http.xxx`).

Comment: yes yes, that was what i tried anyways, at first, that was what i mean with "tail-function" but i dont know why it dosnt worked. but i will try again.